# buildfarm Krel_import-package checksum error

Tags: ros, buildfarm, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I got a lot of emails from the buildfarm concerning [sourcedebs checksum errors](http://build.ros.org/job/Krel_import-package/52328/console):

```
File "pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-rtabmap/ros-kinetic-rtabmap_0.11.8.orig.tar.gz" is already registered with different checksums!
md5 expected: 43c514654a21568f838c575b3c0baba7, got: 64c9eb84ed9ba85b8cfe31f4eb4296c3
 sha1 expected: 3bfcda7c5e5bc44b8626e1c11a96f25ae95a27a8, got: 0000efe344bdce1d3c063627c77600da3194df6f
sha256 expected: e82ce0b2da9118a8e7a57aab87f757085b087937ca879a8c7d36c20ce1c8503a, got: 73353592d6dfa1eff800236cf96a115592565b7296ab2ec3c99ea5e505b0da84
size expected: 17606507, got: 17606597
There have been errors!
```

Example of the failing job's message:

```
Waiting for the completion of Krel_import-package
Krel_import-package #52328 completed. Result was FAILURE
```

Builds affected are:

```
http://build.ros.org/job/Ksrc_uX__rtabmap__ubuntu_xenial__source/
http://build.ros.org/job/Ksrc_uW__rtabmap__ubuntu_wily__source/
```

Repository: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap-release

Maybe related to:

- https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm/issues/119
- https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/issues/233
- https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm/issues/21

Is this could be fixed just by redoing a `bloom-release`?

cheers,

Mathieu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244681/buildfarm-krel_import-package-checksum-error/) by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6409 on 2016-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-09-28**:
Just noticed (https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/406) that my `python-bloom` version (0.5.20) was not the latest one (0.5.22). I just [released](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/12845) again a new version, hope this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think it's the version of bloom that was the problem but that you retagged content before that release: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/12841#issuecomment-249987345

Changing tagged content violates assumptions that the build pipeline makes about data consistency. Version tagged content is not expected to change.

The rerelease probably cleared the cached content at some level.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1